# CSS Grid overflows when minmax(0, 1fr)

Tags: html, css

I am using a Grid to layout my page. The problem when i add to much to the Content `marked with X` it overflows either to the right or bottom and moves the footer out of border.

Is there a way where i set the Content to the remaining width and height of the full screen?

```
+-------+------------------------------------------+
|       |                                          |
|       +------------------------------------------+
|       |                                          |
|       |                                          |
|       |                                          |
|       |                   x                      |
|       |                                          |
|       |                                          |
|       |                                          |
|       |                                          |
|       +------------------------------------------+
|       |                                          |
+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

In my scss i set the grid container i tried to inclued heigt and max-height + overflow to catch anything flowing over the displayed page but it just pushes the footer down and takes up everything.

My SCSS:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
    gap: 0 0;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-areas: "navbar header" "navbar content" "navbar footer";


    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    .content {
        grid-area: content;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #0002;

        ::ng-deep {
            >* {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                flex-wrap: nowrap;
                flex-grow: 1;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
        }

        router-outlet {
            position: absolute;
            min-height: 0 !important;
            height: 0 !important;
            max-height: 0 !important;
        }
    }

    .header {
        grid-area: header;
    }

    .navbar {
        grid-area: navbar;
    }

    .footer {
        float: bottom;
        grid-area: footer;
    }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div 
    class="container">
    <div 
        class="content">
        <router-outlet>

        </router-outlet>
        <ng-content>

        </ng-content>
    </div>
    <div 
        class="header">
        <header>

        </header>
    </div>
    <div 
        class="navbar">
        <navbar>

        </navbar>
    </div>
    <div 
        class="footer">
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: overflow: auto to content ?

Comment: sadly its not that simple, i tried overflow: auto on like everthing with height and max-height...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body,
html {
  /* position: relative;
  height: 1vh; */
  line-height: 1.52857143;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #f5f7fa;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "MetaNormal";
  color: var(--dbl-text-color);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
  gap: 0 0;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar header""navbar content""navbar footer";
}

.content {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-area: content;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0002;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.footer {
  float: bottom;
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: blue;
}

.ng-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="ng-content">
          here is the content with scrollbar
          <div class="page">
            test
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header">
        <p>
          head
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <p>
          navbar
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>
          foot
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```